# ¿ Cómo usar fill_between de matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning

Estoy intentanto hacer un gráfico que debe mostrar varias curvas de errores para comparar. Una de las cosas que deseo es NO solo presentar el valor medio, sino los valores máximo y mínimo que se obtienen después de realizar varias veces el mismo algoritmo. No hace falta que comente que tipo de problema es pero si de que podais ver como es el DataFrame que se usa para la gráfica.

resultados_
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código para hacer la gráfica es :

```
plt.close
width=18
height=8

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(width, height))


color1='green'
line1= ax1.plot(resultados_.max_features, resultados_.oob_error, color=color1, label='oob_error')
line2= ax1.plot(resultados_.max_features, resultados_.test_error, color='pink', label='test_error')
ax1.set_ylabel('Error', color=color1)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color1)
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='red')
ax1.set_xlabel('max_features', color='red', fontweight='bold', fontsize=24)


color2= 'blue'
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

line3= ax2.plot(resultados_.max_features, resultados_.tiempo, color='yellow', label ='Time')


ax2.set_ylabel('Time', color=color2)

lines = line1 + line2 +line3
labels = [l.get_label() for l in lines]
ax1.legend(lines, labels);


###  linea da error
### ax1.fill_between(resultados_.max_features, resultados_.min_oob_error,  resultados_.max_test_error, color="agua")




x = resultados_['max_features'].astype('float')
y= resultados_['tiempo'].astype('float')
slope, intercept, r, p, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)

def myfunc(x):
  return slope * x + intercept


mymodel = list(map(myfunc, x))
ax2.plot(x, mymodel, color=color2)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color2)
```

Y el gáfico que me sale SIN la linea que me da error es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que las curvas obb y test error, además de mostrar los valores medios dibujasen los valores min y max.  Sería intentar hacer algo parecido a :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se trata de saber usar

```
###  linea da error
### ax1.fill_between(resultados_.max_features, resultados_.min_oob_error,  resultados_.max_test_error, color="agua")
```

y esta claro que yo no sé.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

NOTA: El error que más me da con muchas variaciones que he realizado es
`ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solución aunque no entiendo muy bien el motivo. Se trataba de convertirlo en con .astype('float'). Adjunto todo el código y la imagen. Gracias.

```
     color1='green'
     line1= ax1.plot(resultados_.max_features.astype('float'), 
               resultados_.oob_error.astype('float'), color=color1, 
               label='oob_error')
     line2= ax1.plot(resultados_.max_features, resultados_.test_error, 
               color='red', label='test_error')
     line3=  ax1.fill_between(resultados_.max_features.astype('float'), 
                     resultados_.min_oob_error.astype('float'),
                     resultados_.max_oob_error.astype('float'), color ='lime')
     line4=  ax1.fill_between(resultados_.max_features.astype('float'), 
                     resultados_.min_test_error.astype('float'),
                     resultados_.max_test_error.astype('float'), color ='pink')


      ax1.set_ylabel('Error', color=color1)
      ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color1)
      ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='red')
      ax1.set_xlabel('max_features', color='red', fontweight='bold', 
                    fontsize=24)


    color2= 'blue'
    ax2 = ax1.twinx()

    line5= ax2.plot(resultados_.max_features, resultados_.tiempo, 
                    color='yellow', label ='Time')


       ax2.set_ylabel('Time', color=color2)

       lines = line1 + line2 +line5
       labels = [l.get_label() for l in lines]
       ax1.legend(lines, labels);
       x = resultados_['max_features'].astype('float')
       y= resultados_['tiempo'].astype('float')
       slope, intercept, r, p, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)

       def myfunc(x):
           return slope * x + intercept


      mymodel = list(map(myfunc, x))
      ax2.plot(x, mymodel, color=color2)
      ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]